# Question on integral expression of positive definite matrices

Tags: matrix-analysis

> Is there any integral expression for $\log (X + Y) - \log  (X)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are positive definite matrices?

Could anyone give some suggestion as to how to find such an integral expression if there is any?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: can you give an example of the type of integral expression you are hoping for? I am not even sure what would be an "integral expression" for the matrix $X$ by itself...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I suspect that the OP is looking for a matrix-valued generalization of $\log (x+y) - \log (x) = \int _0 ^1 \frac y {x + ty} \, \mathrm d t$.

Comment: @Daflo Beenakker$:$ Perhaps it is related to spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @AlexM. -- thanks, I don't think a single integral of this type will work, I have written a double integral expression in the answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085547/87355)
$$\frac{d}{ds}\log Z(s) = \int_0^1  [(1-t)I+tZ(s)]^{-1}Z'(s) [(1-t)I+tZ(s)]^{-1}\, dt,$$
with $Z(s)=X+sY$, gives upon integration of
$$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds}\log Z(s)\,ds=\log Z(1)-\log Z(0)$$
an integral expression for
$$\log(X+Y)-\log X=\int_0^1\int_0^1  [(1-t)I+t(X+sY)]^{-1} Y [(1-t)I+t(X+sY)]^{-1}\, dt\,ds.$$